# Add Azure App Service to new VNet Integration preview

Tags: azure, powershell, templates, deployment, azure-resource-manager

We want to connect an Azure App Service with our On Premise Network via the new VNet Integration (preview), which doesn't need any Point-to-Site Tunnel anymore. 
We already achieved our goal via Azure Portal and now want to implement this in our DevOps Pipelines via ARM Template Deploy or Powershell.

**ARM Template Deploy:**
We generated the ARM Template from an exisiting App Service with new VNet Integration. Redeploy this Template doesn't add the new VNet Integration, but the old one (very strange):

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections",
    "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_name'), parameters('subnet_name'))]",
    "location": "West Europe",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_name'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "vnetResourceId": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_externalid'), '/subnets/XXXXXXX')]",
        "certThumbprint": null,
        "certBlob": null,
        "routes": null,
        "resyncRequired": false,
        "dnsServers": null,
        "isSwift": true
    }
}
```

**Powershell Deploy:**
Trying this code will add the old VNet Integration as well:

```
$propertiesObject = @{
 "vnetResourceId" = "/subscriptions/$($subscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$($vnet.ResourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$($vnet.Name)/subnets/$($subnetNameToAdd)"
}

$virtualNetwork = New-AzureRmResource -Location $location -Properties $PropertiesObject -ResourceName "$($webAppName)/$($vnet.Name)" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections" -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Force
```

Is this another new feature from Microsoft which is just half implemented and semi available?
(yeah, its in preview, but since several month...)

Comment: why do you think its strange? same code does same thing. whats strange here?

Comment: The code of the ARM Template above is the code of an existing app service with NEW VNet Integration. But when I export the ARM template and deploy a new app service, it will be deployed with OLD VNet integration. Tell me that this is not strange?

Comment: means your code is wrong, thats it ;)

Comment: Its not "my" code, its the code of Azure. I did not touch the code, just downloaded it and redeployed it. Then I should get the same result, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how I got it to work:

```
{
    "name": "vnet_name/subnet_name",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
    "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
        "addressPrefix": "10.0.1.0/24",
        "delegations": [
            {
                "name": "delegation",
                "properties": {
                    "servicename": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "name": "webappname/virtualNetwork",
    "properties": {
        "subnetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'vnet_name', 'subnet_name')]",
        "swiftSupported": true
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'vnet_name', 'subnet_name')]"
    ],
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "apiVersion": "2018-02-01"
}
```

Comment: thanks! Found nowhere the ressource type "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets". Works!